# Sets which are unions of translates of each other but aren't single translates

Tags: gr.group-theory, abelian-groups

I'm a hobbyist mathematician so any question I ask here might be at risk of closure. I hope this one is good enough, but I'm not sure. This is a continuation of two questions I asked on math.stackexchange.com: [About translating subsets of $\Bbb R^2$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/309619/about-translating-subsets-of-bbb-r2) and [About translating subsets of $\Bbb Z$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/872588/about-translating-subsets-of-bbb-z). The question is

> For which abelian groups $M$ can we find $A,B\subseteq M$ such that
>
> - $A$ is a union of translated (only translations are allowed) copies of $B$;
> - $B$ is a union of translated copies of $A$;
> - $A$ is not a a single translated copy of $B$ (and the other way around, which follows)?

David Moews showed in an answer to the first question that such sets exist in $\Bbb Z^\omega$ and therefore in any group in which $\Bbb Z^\omega$ embeds. Certainly no such sets can be found in finite groups. Can we describe all groups that have such two sets?

Comment: For those who might not follow the MSE link: $\mathbb Z^\omega$ here denotes direct sum, not Cartesian product. That is, such sets exist in any abelian group of infinite rank.

Comment: Generalizing the finite case, there are no such sets in torsion groups, and they satisfy the stronger condition that $A=A+X$ implies $A=A+t$ for every $t\in X$.

Comment: @Emil so this means that if the property of not having such sets is closed under finite products, then this property is just the finiteness of rank, right?

Comment: I don't know whether it is realistic to expect the property to be closed under products, but anyway, then you'd still need to prove it holds for $\mathbb Q$, it's not enough to have it for $\mathbb Z$.

Comment: @Emil Oh, right. I'll try to think about the case of Q.  It seems interesting in its own right to me.

Comment: Actually, I didn’t say it right. If an abelian group is not finitely generated, it’s not necessarily a product of a torsion and torsion-free group, so even if it works for $\mathbb Q$, closure under finite products is not enough. You’d need closure under extensions.

Comment: Here’s one thing to keep in mind. Consider a mild strengthening of the property: if $B=A+X$ and $A=B+Y$ with $X$ nonempty, then $B=A+t$ *for* *some* $t\in X$. This holds for torsion groups and for $\mathbb Z$, but it fails for all nontrivial torsion-free groups not isomorphic to $\mathbb Z$ (in particular, $\mathbb Z^2$ and $\mathbb Q$). The reason is any such group can be endowed with a nondiscrete total order, and then taking the set of all strictly positive elements as $A=B=X=Y$ gives a counterexample to the strengthened property.

Comment: Anyway, if you don't mind countable and highly overlapping unions, $y>\sqrt 2 x$ and $y>\sqrt 2 x+\frac 12$ is a simple explicit pair in $\mathbb Z^2$.

Comment: @fedja Perhaps you could post it as an answer to the question about $\Bbb R^2?$ It's much simpler than David Moews' answer I think. Or I can post it if you don't feel like it and don't mind.